# Oscilloscope measurement of square wave

Tags: arduino, oscilloscope, pulse

I am using my Arduino uno to generate a 500Hz Square wave between 0 and 5 volts. I am measuring the signal from the Arduino using an oscilloscope and instead of measuring 5 volts peak to peak, it measures 500 millivolts. I have checked everything and cannot find anywhere a mistake. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Is your oscilloscope set to high impedance?

Comment: Does “everything” include the 10:1 probe scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your scope and scope probe scaling are set to the same setting. If your scope probe is set to 10x, make sure your scope is set to 10x.

Comment: Would it be a problem if I set both to 1x ?

Comment: @TeoProtoulis 10x is better. I'll let you conduct your own research as to why.